# Trying to get twitter posts from specific user

Tags: jquery, json, api, twitter

I am using the following code to grab the twitter data from a specific user and outputting it to a div, However it is not working. Nothing is outputting, I am really not sure if I am doing this right, I took this forked this snippet from someone else. I am not sure if I need to authenticate with twitter and how to do so?

http://jsfiddle.net/elijahmanor/Nstnx/22/

Js

```
$(function(){    

    var twitterUsername = 'anderskitson'
    var url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/" + 
        twitterUsername + 
        ".json?count=5&callback=?";
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        var twitterList = $( "<ul />" );
        $.each( data, function( index, item ) {
            $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
                .appendTo( twitterList );
        });
        $( "#output" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
            $( this ).empty()
                .append( twitterList )
                .fadeIn( "slow" );            
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old form of the URL. That form has been deprecated. You also need to add `callback=something` to the URL so that it will use JSONP and get past the cross origin issue. Also, update your jQuery to the latest version. The fiddle was using an old version.

Try this code:

```
$( "#getTweets" ).bind( "click", function() {
    var twitterUsername = $( "#twitterUsername" ).val();
    var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&count=2&callback=jsonp&screen_name=" + 
        twitterUsername;
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        var twitterList = $( "<ul />" );
        $.each( data, function( index, item ) {
            $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
                .appendTo( twitterList );
        });
        $( "#output" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
            $( this ).empty()
                .append( twitterList )
                .fadeIn( "slow" );            
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried that in my jsfiddle and it doesnt seem to work I just get a black line as my output http://jsfiddle.net/BntSH/

Comment: When I visit the url I get a rate limited error, could that be my issue?

Comment: Authenticate. That way you can upgrade to version 1.1 of the API too.

Comment: How Do I Go about authenticating?